# Can someone explain the use of Fabric CA when using cryptogen tool?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Am following the Build Your First Network - [Link](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/first-network)

When you issue the below command, the byfn.sh script creates all your initial cryptographic material using the cryptogen tool and then also brings up a Fabric CA for each of your Orgs (along with CouchDB to store your world state).

```
./byfn.sh -m generate
./byfn.sh -m up -s couchdb -a
```

In this scenario, what would the CA be used for?